# Workflow to make the same edit in all word documents in a particular library or site

Tags: workflow, word, edit, online

I am using sharepoint online. Ì have been trying to find a way to open all word documents in my document library and make a same edit in all the word document footer. I can do that manually, but there are some 1500 word files. Can I use a workflow to automate the process.

Can this workflow be linked to all libraries in a site simultaneously or individually.

Comment: My end requirement is to have a the current data inserted at the bottom every time a document is published or printed. Preferably in the footer or on the bottom of the front page. Word has this feature inbuilt to insert current date. But I will have to make the update in each file and prefer to automate. Either all the files can be updated together or files updated every time the file is printed or published.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, using SharePoint designer workflow, it is not possible to open a word document, update the footer in it and save it, because there is no OOTB action to perform this task in SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow.

Comment: I hav'nt found any solution as of now as well. Hope there is an option